# Sending multiple messages using twilio, node and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, twilio

I have a client who owns a cellphone shop and he wants to gather customer numbers and send weekly/monthly offers to them.
I use MySQL and Node JS, is it possible to send an SMS to multiple numbers through using MySQL database inside twilio node code ? 
For example, we have a MySQL DB table called "customers" which has "custid", "custname" and "custnumber" columns, which basically gathers the numbers through his website (a subscription form on his website where customer names and numbers get automatically added to the DB when a customer submits). I want to use this table in twilio node code so that I don't hardtype numbers every time(in the twilio code) I want to send an offer to multiple customers.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm asking if it is possible and sort of hints to get it done. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yep it's possible, you need to use [twillio nodejs module](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/) and [nodejs mysql module](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)

Comment: Alright I will try, thanks.